# Docker for Azure - no swarm mode?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-swarm

I just tried [Docker 4 Azure Beta](https://beta.docker.com/docs/azure/release-notes/), but I'm confused right at the beginning.
When I SSH into docker manager VM and do `docker info` or `docker service ls` I see that there is no swarm enabled?
Why? What's going on here? Do I have to enable it by myself? But as I understand, I have no option to SSH into my worker nodes, so how would I do this?

Or is there some "azure-clustering" configured instead of Docker Swarm? But why would they do so - and how can I manage my cluster/swarm in that case (scaling container count up and down)?

Answer (score 1):

After you login to one of the manager VMs, you should be able to execute `docker node ls` and see all the VMs brought up through the ARM template as part of the swarm. The swarm should have been configured for you as part of the VM bring-up. Did you correctly generate an Azure Service Principal and pass in the credential details to the ARM template?

Answer (score -1):

Old school Docker clustering (swarm) is supported out of the box.
Swarm Mode is available in the UK region at the moment.

I was wondering why running a custom template gives me the option to select Swarm Mode and also asks if I am in the UK, then I found [this](https://dgkanatsios.com/2017/07/10/deploying-a-docker-swarm-mode-cluster-on-azure-container-service/)!

I'll give it a try to check what happens if I select swarm mode but I am quite certain the deployment will fail since my account is in Greece.